# ORDER BY within multiple database query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am running the below SQL query in SSMS and it works perfectly.

However, I want to add an `ORDER BY suname` to this. I know this is meant to go at the end of `UNION ALL` in a standard query, but I am not sure where to put it when running the query on multiple databases at once.

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);                 
SET @Sql =                  
STUFF(                  
(SELECT                 
    NCHAR(10) + N'UNION ALL' + NCHAR(10) +                  
N'SELECT                    
        LEFT('+ QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + N', LEN('+ QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + N') - 12) AS Office,         
        pt_copysupp COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as Supplier_Code,            
        suname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as Supplier_Name,         
        pt_trantype COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as Tran_Type,            
        pt_gross as Local_Gross,           
        pt_currencycode COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as Foreign_Currency_Code,            
        pt_curr_valu as Foreign_Currency_Gross            
            FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.pl_transactions      
                inner join ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.pl_accounts on ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.pl_transactions.pt_copysupp = ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.pl_accounts.sucode    
                where pt_trantype in (''INV'', ''CRN'') 
                    and pt_date between ''2020-01-01'' and ''2020-12-31'''
FROM sys.databases d                    
WHERE name LIKE '%AccountsLive'                 
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)                 
.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 11, '');                    

EXEC (@Sql);
```

If I put it at the end of the query like usual, like the below, I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near UNION

and running print debug of course puts this order by at the end of each database query, which is incorrect as this is just meant to be once and right at the end of the query like usual `ORDER BY` queries.

```
and pt_date between ''2020-01-01'' and ''2020-12-31''
order by SUNAME'
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

EDIT: I have changed the column names as previously was incorrect (thanks @Gordan Linoff for pointing this out!)

Answer (score 3):

You have renamed the column:

```
   suname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as Suppler,
```

In fact, you have renamed *all* the columns to the same name.  I would suggest removing the `as Suppler` from all the column definitions.  Then the `order by` should work.

As for where the `order by` go, you can use:

```
set @sql = @sql + ' order by suname';
```

It goes at the end of the query; in this case, the last line.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for spotting the column names....not sure what happened there, but have updated the question so it's not all the same!! Regarding your `set @sql = @sql + ' order by suname';` answer, when I put this after the `pt_date between` line, I get an `incorrect syntax near ;` error....not sure if I am putting it in the correct please?

Comment: @PeterK . . . That logic goes after the first `set @sql=`, right before the `exec`.

Comment: Hmm I am getting `ORDER BY items must appear in select list if statement contains UNION, INTERESCT or EXCEPT operator`....

Comment: @PeterK . . . You need to be sure that alias is defined correctly.  Or, you can just use `order by <n>` where `<n>` is the column position.